# How to set a CVPixelBuffer as an input for a vertex shader?

Tags: ios, rendering, metal

I would like to use Apple Metal render path for processing a CVPixelBuffer.

How can i transform a CVPixelBuffer so it would conform as an input for a vertex shader?
Not sure how to extract the color/position values from a CVPixelBuffer so i would be able setting them from the host.

Comment: Vertex buffers usually contain X,Y,Z coordinates for a 3D object, not RGB values for pixels. Maybe you want to create a Texture instead?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code I use to convert CVPixelBuffer data to a Metal texture.

```
#pragma mark - AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
  CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

  id<MTLTexture> texture = nil;

  {
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);

    MTLPixelFormat pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm;

    CVMetalTextureRef metalTextureRef = NULL;
    CVReturn status = CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(NULL, _textureCache, pixelBuffer, NULL, pixelFormat, width, height, 0, &metalTextureRef);
    if(status == kCVReturnSuccess)
    {
      texture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(metalTextureRef);
      if (self.delegate){
        [self.delegate textureUpdated:texture];
      }
      CFRelease(metalTextureRef);
    }
  }
}
```

After you have a texture, you just pass it to renderCommandEncoder. If you need help with that, let me know in comments.

Comment: Hey Haawa! Couple things i'm trying to understand from your code: if you set the pixel format to MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm, it means you changed the video settings to send the buffers with BGRA pixels, right?

Comment: I'm currently using this functionality with depth maps and I'm thinking it's highly likely that it's losing a lot of precision - you can see definite 'steps' in the depth map when applying some filters.

Comment: I used this way to convert CVPixelBuffer to MTLTexture, but the XCode GPU Capture Profile told me there was a insight : "CoreVideo Missing Usage Flags", I think it means that the MTLTexture created by this way doesn't have usage flag, so does anyone know how to add a flag when creating by this way?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

- Create a texture.
- Copy the CVPixelBuffer into the texture with [replaceRegion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MTLTexture_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MTLTexture/replaceRegion:mipmapLevel:slice:withBytes:bytesPerRow:bytesPerImage:)
- Use [getBaseAddress](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CVPixelBufferRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress) as the first argument.
- Do not create a vertex buffer. You don't need it.
- Create a vertex shader in Metal.
- Take UInt vid [[vertex_id]] as a input to your vertex shader function.
- When you call drawPrimitives specify vertexCount:width*height.

vid will go from 0 to width*height. You can then sample your texture based on the value of vid.

Keep in mind:

- The pixel buffer might pad sizes up to nearest 4 or 8.
- Textures are sampled with normalized coordinates from 0.0 to 1.0. Not pixel coordinates.

Comment: Thanks to @karsten for fixing up a couple of things, that for some reason was rejected. I have made the same edits to the answer.